# Probability that brothers are identical twins

Tags: probability

> *Mother's blood type is 0, and father's blood type is AB. They have twins - two sons - and they both have blood type B. What is the probability that they are identical twins, knowing that 32% of all twins have different gender?*

I calculated that the probability of getting blood type B in such case is 0.5, so there's 25% chance that two kids are type B. I want to use the formula for conditional probability, but how do I calculate the chance of twins being identical and blood type B? And what should be in the denominator? I am confused.

Comment: Two steps using conditional probability and Bayes' formula : (a) use the $32\%$ to calculate the prior probability that twins both boys are identical; (b) use the shared blood type B to find the posterior probability that these twin boys are identical

Comment: I don't get what the question is asking. The probability that mother and father have two sons with blood type B?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: I think the question is: Among all twin births to a 0 mother and an AB father, where the twins are both boys and both B, in which fraction of those are the twins _identical_ twins?

Comment: @HenningMakholm That is not possible to answer, because the definition of "identical twin" is a biological one.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Well it *is* possible to answer if you know the difference between a non-identical and an identical twin.

Answer (score 0):

> calculated that the probability of getting blood type B in such case is 0.5, so there's 25% chance that two kids are type B.

To be precise, there is a $25\%$ probability for both being type B, when they are *non-identical* twins.  (PS: What are we assuming here?  Is that okay?)

What is the probability for both being type B, when they are *identical* twins?

$$\mathsf P(B\mid \neg I)=0.25, \mathsf P(B\mid I)=\bbox[2pt,border:dotted 1pt]{\qquad?}$$

$$\mathsf P(I\mid B) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(B\mid I)\mathsf P(I)}{\mathsf P(B\mid I)\mathsf P(I)+\mathsf P(B\mid \neg I)(1-\mathsf P(I))}$$

So all we need is to estimate $\mathsf P(I)$

Well, what does the information about shared gender of *all* twins tell us about that?    In the same vein, what can you say about probability that identical twins share the same gender, what might you assume about the probability that non-identical twins do (is it a reasonable assumption), and what do you do next?

---

> Hint: Use the Law of Total Probability.